# Merge Sort isn't returning the correct answer

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort

I am writing a merge sort algorithm. I don't get any compile errors, but when I run the algorithm the expected result should be the given array sorted. 
The result I get is just a 0.

```
def mergeSort(array):
    temp = []
    if (len(array) <= 1):
        return array

    halfWay = len(array) // 2
    bottom = mergeSort(array[:halfWay])
    top = mergeSort(array[halfWay:])
    bottomLen = len(bottom)
    topLen = len(top)
    i = 0
    j = 0

    while i != bottomLen or j != topLen:
        if (i != bottomLen and (j == topLen or bottom[i] < top[j])):
            temp.append(bottom[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            temp.append(top[j])
            j += 1

        return temp


array = [10, 7, 14, 2, 5, 12, 17, 9, 0, 1]
ar = mergeSort(array)
print(" ".join(str(x) for x in ar))
```

Comment: `return temp` probably should not be inside the `while` loop. Maybe remove a level of indent?

Comment: Your return is inside the while loop. So it runs once and then returns

Comment: I looked at that for far too long!
Thanks guys! :)

Comment: Don't just stare at things and try to figure it out. Actually *debug*; that is, trace through the execution of the program, and verify that various things have the values you expect at various points in the process.

Comment: This is a typical example of the downside of relying solely on indentation for program structure. Python programmers see this as cool and even elegant, until they spend a few hours staring at a bug like this one, hiding in plain sight. To avoid such pitfalls, one must learn to use debugging tools, especially for tracing programs line by line, and implement systematic tests.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation for return line is wrong. it is now in while loop, which it should not

```
def mergeSort(array):
    temp = []
    if(len(array) <= 1):
        return array

    halfWay = len(array) // 2
    bottom = mergeSort(array[:halfWay])
    top = mergeSort(array[halfWay:])
    bottomLen = len(bottom)
    topLen = len(top)
    i = 0
    j = 0

    while i != bottomLen or j != topLen:
        if(i != bottomLen and (j == topLen or bottom[i] < top[j])):
            temp.append(bottom[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            temp.append(top[j])
            j += 1

    return temp
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement is inside the `while` loop, causing an early return with an array containing the smallest element.

Another note: the function returns its argument for lengths `0` and `1` and a new array otherwise. This is inconsistent and might cause problems if the returned object is later modified by the caller. You should either modify the array received as an argument and return it or always return a new array.

Here are 2 modified versions:

```py
# version that modifies the array in place
def mergeSort(array):
    arrayLen = len(array)
    if (arrayLen <= 1):
        return array

    bottomLen = arrayLen // 2
    bottom = mergeSort(array[:bottomLen])
    top = mergeSort(array[bottomLen:])
    topLen = len(top)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0

    while k < arrayLen:
        if (i < bottomLen and (j == topLen or bottom[i] < top[j])):
            array[k] = bottom[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        else:
            array[k] = top[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

    return array
```

```py
# version that returns a new array
def mergeSort(array):
    arrayLen = len(array)
    temp = []
    if (arrayLen <= 1):
        if (arrayLen == 1): temp.append(array[0])
        return temp

    bottomLen = len(array) // 2
    bottom = mergeSort(array[:bottomLen])
    top = mergeSort(array[bottomLen:])
    topLen = len(top)
    i = 0
    j = 0

    while i != bottomLen or j != topLen:
        if (i != bottomLen and (j == topLen or bottom[i] < top[j])):
            temp.append(bottom[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            temp.append(top[j])
            j += 1

    return temp
```